# How to delay UI feedback before combobox is opened in WP 8.1

Tags: events, windows-phone-8.1

I need to add delay (2000ms) directly after a combobox control is touched. There shouldn't be any kind of feedback to the user after the touch but only after the delay. How this can be done in WP 8.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same answer as for your AppBarButton, edit the style and replace the button by a RepeatButton with a delay. Here is the extract of the ComboBox style:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Style="{StaticResource HeaderContentPresenterStyle}"
    FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}"
    Visibility="Collapsed"
    Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" 
    Margin="0,0,0,-4.5"/>
    <!-- Presenter for selection/placeholder text when #items is > 5 -->
<RepeatButton x:Name="FlyoutButton" Delay="2000"
    Grid.Row="1"
    FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
    FontSize="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}"
    FontWeight="Normal"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
    Padding="6.5,0,0,0"
    MinHeight="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemMinHeightThemeSize}">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" MinHeight="32.5" Margin="0,0.8,0,0">
      <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock"
        Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxPlaceholderTextBlockStyle}"
        Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" margin="0"/>
    </ContentPresenter>
</RepeatButtonButton>
```